# No type erasure warning on partial function with abstract type

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, type-erasure

The following definition doesn't trigger any warning on scala 2.10.4:

```
class NoWarning[T] {
  def f: PartialFunction[Any, T] = { case x: List[T] => x.head }
}
```

However this one does (as expected) on scala 2.10.4, but **not** on 2.11.1:

```
class WithWarning {
  def f[T]: PartialFunction[Any, T] = { case x: List[T] => x.head }
}
```

1. Why does the first definition not trigger a warning at all?
2. Why does the second definition not trigger a warning on scala 2.11.1?

Comment: Neither of these is type-safe, it is easy to get `ClassCastException` from either. I think this is a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

[Odersky explains](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/M9DK5AQCoeA/lw102gfTd_AJ) a difference in pattern matching depending on whether the type param is on the method or class.

I assume that's because of subclassing.